# encrypting and decrypting on python

Tags: python, encryption, indentation, caesar-cipher

How do I solve this? It keeps telling me that I can't put {elif} function after {CodedLetter} and I understand why, but seen as I also can't put the {if} function because the same thing comes up, I don't know what else to do. Does anyone one know what I could use either instead of {while}or {elif}.

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
Welcome = print("Hello there...")
print("~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~")
print("¦        1. Encrypt message         ¦")
print("¦        2. Decrypt message         ¦")
print("¦             3. Exit               ¦")
print("~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~")

while Welcome is '1':
def Cipher(alphabet,UpperAlphabet,message,shift,FinalMessage):
    for x in message:
        if x in alphabet:
            CodedLetter = alphabet[(int(alphabet.index(x))+shift)%(len(alphabet))]
        FinalMessage += CodedLetter
    elif x in UpperAlphabet:
        CodedLetter = UpperAlphabet[(int(UpperAlphabet.index(x))+shift)%(len(UpperAlphabet))]
        FinalMessage += CodedLetter
    elif x == " ":
        CodedLetter = x
        FinalMessage += CodedLetter
return(FinalMessage)

alphabet = "".join(chr(x) for x in range(65,91))
UpperAlphabet = "".join(chr(x) for x in range(97,123))
message = input("Write your message")
shift = int(input("Enter shift amount"))
Word = []
FinalMessage = " "
print(Cipher(alphabet,UpperAlphabet,message,shift,FinalMessage))

while Welcome is '2':
def Cipher(alphabet,UpperAlphabet,message,shift,FinalMessage):
    for x in message:
        if x in alphabet:
            CodedLetter = alphabet[(int(alphabet.index(x))+shift)%(len(alphabet))]
        FinalMessage += CodedLetter
      elif x in UpperAlphabet:
        CodedLetter = UpperAlphabet[(int(UpperAlphabet.index(x))+shift)%(len(UpperAlphabet))]
         FinalMessage += CodedLetter
      elif x == " ":
      CodedLetter = x
        FinalMessage += CodedLetter
return(FinalMessage)

alphabet = "".join(chr(x) for x in range(65,91))
UpperAlphabet = "".join(chr(x) for x in range(97,123))
message = input("Write your message")
shift = int(input("Enter shift amount"))
Word = []
FinalMessage = " "
print(Cipher(alphabet,UpperAlphabet,message,shift,FinalMessage))

while welcome is '3':
exit()
```

Comment: Your code is not indented correctly. Push your `elif` by 1 tab (or spaces..)

Comment: Also instead `while welcome is '3':` use `if welcome == '3':` and pay attention that you use `Welcome` all the time and just `welcome` once... Many problems with your code..

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of duplicate code... let's fix that..

First define only 2 functions for the Caesar Cipher. One to encrypt and decrypt a character, and the other for an entire string.

A positive `shift` is an encryption, a negative `shift` is decryption.

```
def cipher_character(character, shift):
    # Don't convert anything other than english characters
    if not character.isalpha():
        return character
    # declare some helping constants
    alpha_length = 26
    ascii_shift = ord('A') if character.isupper() else ord('a')
    cipher_shift = shift % alpha_length

    # shift down to 0..25 for a..z
    shifted = ord(character) - ascii_shift
    # rotate the letter and handle "wrap-around" for negatives and value >= 26
    shifted = (shifted + cipher_shift + alpha_length) % alpha_length
    # shift back up to english characters
    return chr(shifted + ascii_shift)

# Rotate a string k-positions
def cipher_string(string, shift):
    return ''.join(cipher_character(c, shift) for c in string)
```

Next, prompt for your user input

```
print("Hello there...")
print("~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~")
print("¦        1. Encrypt message         ¦")
print("¦        2. Decrypt message         ¦")
print("¦             3. Exit               ¦")
print("~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~")
option = input()
```

Then, do some if-checks for the option that the user entered.

```
if option == '1' or option == '2':
    message = input("Write your message: ")

    if option == '1':
        shift = int(input("Enter shift amount: "))
    else:
        shift = -1*int(input("Enter un-shift amount: "))

    print(cipher_string(message, shift))
elif option == '3':
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)
```

Place all this in one file with the same indentation as here and you should be good.

---

An example run would look like

```
$ python3 CeasarCipher.py
Hello there...
~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~
¦        1. Encrypt message         ¦
¦        2. Decrypt message         ¦
¦             3. Exit               ¦
~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~
1
Write your message: This is a test
Enter shift amount: 4
Xlmw mw e xiwx
```

---

```
$ python3 CeasarCipher.py
Hello there...
~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~
¦        1. Encrypt message         ¦
¦        2. Decrypt message         ¦
¦             3. Exit               ¦
~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~
2
Write your message: Xlmw mw e xiwx
Enter un-shift amount: 4
This is a test
```

Comment: @zaph [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) uses `n`. What would you recommend?

Comment: Interestingly variables beginning with or a single letter i, j, k, l, m, m were integers, all other variables were real. That partly explains k and n. But that was over 50 years ago and things have progressed. perhaps `encryptOrDecrypt`. `c` could also be `character`. Perhaps: `def cipherCharacter(character, encryptOrDecrypt):`, that seems to read nicely.

Comment: Verbose variable names are a personal choice, but for clarity, I will make the appropriate edits.

Comment: Yes, how we write code is a personal choice, note I did not down vote. The way the OP wrote his code was also a personal choice but I like your choice better. It is that personal choice that separates coding from engineering.

Comment: It *is* an encryption algorithm, so cryptic variable names are appropriate IMO :) anyways, made the edits.